# AWS Lambda Python 3.x Runtime call PowerShell Script?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, aws-lambda

I need to run a PowerShell script from a python-runtime lambda on AWS.  Of course the alternative is to run a dotnet lambda instead but our team is mainly Python and the process itself has been proven to work locally successfully so the thought of re-doing everything in C# is not overly appetizing and would be time consuming.  I am wondering if there is anyone out here in the SO world that has either done it or knows that it *can* be done?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but lambda does now allow custom runtimes, so you could create a PowerShell runtime.

Comment: and that was actually something I was thinking about, could I essentially run docker with a python-runtime lambda where PS was an install?  In other words, could I create a serverless, customized ec2 instance that is hosted on a lambda?

Comment: The official Powershell7 custom runtime experience has improved a lot since the question, here's an intro https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-powershell-custom-runtime-for-aws-lambda/